# How can I use secrets from a GitHub environment to pass it to a reusable workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow, which then uses a reusable workflow. I need to pass a secret, but I want to use [environments](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment) from GitHub to use always the same secret name for different workflows for each environment.

```yaml
on: push

jobs:
  run:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml
    environment: production
    secrets:
      some-super-secret: ${{ secrets.SOME_SUPER_SECRET }}
```

When trying to use the `environment` key in the job, I get:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/workflow.yml (Line: 6, Col: 5): Unexpected value 'environment'
```

The problem is that reusable workflows are limited to being used as a job definition (instead of as a step, as Actions are), as stated in [the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#calling-a-reusable-workflow).

> You call a reusable workflow by using the `uses` keyword. Unlike when you are using actions within a workflow, you call reusable workflows directly within a job, and not from within job steps.

Is there any way to get this working with a reusable workflow?

If not, I am just thinking of changing my reusable workflow to a composite action so that I can define the environment in the job and use my composite action as a step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to set the environment *in the reusable workflow*:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      environment:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      SOME_SUPER_SECRET:
        required: true

jobs:
  <job_id>:
    environment:
      name: ${{ inputs.environment }}
```

and pass it in as a variable from the calling workflow:

```yaml
jobs:
  run:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml
    with:
      environment: production
    secrets:
      SOME_SUPER_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SOME_SUPER_SECRET }}
```

Note you do have to pass down the secrets explicitly (or use [`secrets: inherit`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsecretsinherit)), but they'll be accessible once the environment's set.